# How to programmatically click item in jQuery navigation accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I've spent my allotted time searching for an answer on SO, so here goes. Given this code to create a navigation accordion in js

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    fillSpace: true,
    collapsible: false,
    navigation: true
});
```

and this to populate it in my view (most removed for clarity)

```
 <h2>
    <a href="#">Messages</a></h2>
<ul class="menulist" id="messagesNavItems">
    @Html.MenuItem("Messaging", "InterOffice", "Message", "selected")
    @Html.MenuItem("Outbox", "Outbox", "Message", "selected")
    @Html.MenuItem("Inbox", "Inbox", "Message", "selected")
</ul>
```

which renders

```
<ul id="messagesNavItems" class="bunch of classes" role="tabpanel">
    <li>
        <a href="/Buyer/Message/InterOffice">Messaging</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Buyer/Message/Inbox">Inbox</a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Buyer/Message/Outbox">Outbox</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

How do I simulate the click to Outbox from some other part of the page?

I can get the "Heading" to pop with

```
var accordionindex = 5; /*Messages*/
$("#accordion").accordion('activate', accordionindex);
```

but I need to take it to the next level and "click" the item which would then cause the browser to navigate.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have to give some credit where credit is due, to kannix who suggested the click method on the selector, but in my case for whatever reason that still did not activate the link and and cause navigation to take place.

What I ended up having to do was bind the click event to the anchor first

```
    $("#messagesNavItems a[href$='Inbox']").on('click', function() {
        alert('Inbox was clicked');
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
```

which did respond to the programmatic clicking from outside the jQuery Accordion.

Here's all the pertinent code which first sets the right panel to be opened , then clicks and follows the link.

```
$(function () {

    $("#messagesNavItems a[href$='Inbox']").on('click', function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });

    $('iframe').load(function () {

        $(this).contents().find("a[href='messages/list.asp?pjid=&box=in&sf=mesibox']").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); /* the frame link we are clicking shound not navigate */
            var accordionindex = 5; /*Messages*/
            $("#accordion").accordion('activate', accordionindex);
            $("#messagesNavItems a[href$='Inbox']").click();
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested code:

```
$("#messagesNavItems a[href$='Outbox']").click();
```

Comment: Do you wait for dom ready, before the click? If yes, try to set up a jsfiddle which shows the problem..